# Getting Checkerboard Output when Drawing Text on PIL Image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

When I try to write this text onto a PIL Image, the output does not have the written text, and instead shows a checkerboard pattern in the location where the text is supposed to be.

[image: PIL Image with Text]

Here is my code:

```
font_size = 18
num_lines_possible = h // font_size # height of the bounding box i want to write the text to
for j in range(min(len(lines), num_lines_possible)):
        print(f"lines[j]: {lines[j]}")
        button_draw.text((0, j * font_size), lines[j], font=font_style, fill=t_color)
```

The font_style is chosen randomly from:

```
               fonts = [ImageFont.truetype('/System/Library/Fonts/SFCompact.ttf', size=16), 
                        ImageFont.truetype('/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Verdana Bold.ttf', size=16),
                        ImageFont.truetype('/System/Library/Fonts/Avenir.ttc', size=16),
                        ImageFont.truetype('/System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.ttc', size=16),
                        ImageFont.truetype('/System/Library/Fonts/SFArabic.ttf', size=16)] #, size=12)]
```

Additionally, here is the debugging output of what should be printed (instead of the checkerboard).

```
lines[j]: Bias-Variance Trade-off:
lines[j]: • For a given x, we have a conditional
lines[j]: p(y|x) of sales prices; the Bayesian
lines[j]: prediction of the label value for a
lines[j]: x is Ey[y|x]; • The noise term
lines[j]: the inherent variance in labels y � x �
lines[j]: [Ey[y|x] − y]2p(x, y)dxdy � �� � noise:
lines[j]: due to randomness of y • This term has
lines[j]: to do with our prediction hD(x) x,
lines[j]: Our hammer: Maximum likelihood estimation Optimization
lines[j]: (π∗ c , θ∗ ck) = arg max  � n log πyn + � n,k xnk log θynk  
lines[j]: θ∗ ck = #of times word k shows up in data points labeled as c
lines[j]: trials for data points labeled as c π∗ c = #of data points labeled as
lines[j]: Estimating {θck, k = 1, 2, · · · , K} We want to maximize � n:yn=c,k xnk
lines[j]: θck Intuition • Again similar to roll a dice: each side of the dice shows
lines[j]: with a probability of θck (total K sides) • And we have total � n:yn=c,k
slide_title: HnjRKOMBUYeHrZeGxPCjwg
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Please make sure your code is **minimal, complete and reproducible**. *"Minimal"* means I don't have to find a load of fonts if the issue can be demonstrated with a single font or any font. *"Complete"* means I should be able to copy it and paste it onto my machine and run it - without needing to guess which libraries you used, guess what *"button"* is and so on. Thank you.

Comment: Resolved - this was a problem with a specific font (Arabic), so once I switched the font, the text was displaying normally.